# A more general (Generic ) and better way to serialize API data?

Tags: c#, rest, generics, json-deserialization

I would like to know if my method to get data from coingecko API can be done better and more general. Especially on return, so I don't have to use if for each crypto.   When changing the name of the variables in the API classes the deserialization does not work. Some better way or change API source with better parameters?

```
public async Task<decimal> GetActuallPrice(string cryptoName = "bitcoin")
{
    var rootApiModel = new RootApiModel();

    using HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        Uri jsonUrl = new Uri($"https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids={cryptoName}&vs_currencies=czk");

        var response = await client.GetAsync(jsonUrl);


        string jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        // for bitcoin : {"bitcoin":{"czk":637909}}
        // for ehereum : {"ethereum":{"czk":40590}}

        rootApiModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootApiModel>(jsonString);

        if (cryptoName.ToLower() == "ethereum")
            return rootApiModel.ethereum.czk;

        return rootApiModel.bitcoin.czk;

}

public class RootApiModel
{
    public Bitcoin bitcoin { get; set; }
    public Ethereum ethereum { get; set; }

}

public class Bitcoin
{
    public int czk { get; set; }
}

public class Ethereum
{
    public int czk { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class RootApiModel<T>
{
    public T Crypto { get; set; }

}
```

Does not solve the return problem and adds the need to specify the crypto type when deserializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all possible currencies have data with the same structure (i.e. with JSON property `czk`) then you can use `Dictionary<string, ...>`:

```cs
var js = """{"bitcoin":{"czk":637909}}""";
var res1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Crypto>>(js);
Console.WriteLine(res1.First().Value.czk); // prints 637909

public class Crypto
{
    public int czk { get; set; }
}
```

Another option is to use dynamic capabilities via `JObject` (though I would stick with dictionary approach):

```cs
var res1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(js);
Console.WriteLine(res1.First.First["czk"].ToString());
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, I need to absorb this a little bit. Anyway, JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Crypto>> will raise an error. JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Crypto>> works.

Comment: @Tsko please reload the page. I have updated both snippets to use Json.NET.

Comment: Great, all works fine now.. thanks